# Aligning nodes, keeping labels with edges

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following model:

```
strict digraph graphName {
  rankdir="LR";
  splines="curved";

  age -> intention [label="-"];
  attitude -> intention [label="+"];
  education -> intention [label="+"];
  env_friendly -> intention [label="+"];
  knowledge -> intention [label="+"];
  male
  negative -> intention [label="-"];
  neutral
  positive -> intention [label="+"];
  unsafe -> intention [label="-"];

  positive -> env_friendly [dir="both", label="+"];

  { rank = same; age; attitude; education; env_friendly; knowledge; male; negative; neutral; positive; unsafe; }
}
```

This renders OK but the edge labels are off, and the double-arrow goes into the nodes rather than to the node edge. What must I do to get the labels back with the nodes?

[image]

Comment: Which engine and which version of GraphViz do you use? In http://www.webgraphviz.com/ I think the right graph is shown.

Comment: With dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)(Windows) the lines are doubled and very strange. With dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304) (Cygwin) looks better only the double headed line still goes into the nodes. I needed to set xlabel though instead of label.

Comment: Ah, right, with xlabel it looks a little better. The labels do still appear across the edges, and indeed the arrow goes into the nodes -- I'm using dot 2.40.1 on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the the line `splines = "curved";` gives you what (I guess) you want:

```
strict digraph graphName {
  rankdir="LR";
  # splines="curved";

  age -> intention [label="-"];
  attitude -> intention [label="+"];
  education -> intention [label="+"];
  env_friendly -> intention [label="+"];
  knowledge -> intention [label="+"];
  male
  negative -> intention [label="-"];
  neutral
  positive -> intention [label="+"];
  unsafe -> intention [label="-"];

  positive -> env_friendly [dir="both", label="+"];

  { rank = same; age; attitude; education; env_friendly; knowledge; male; negative; neutral; positive; unsafe; }
}
```

yields

[image]

The hint was in `graphviz`'s warning

> Warning: edge labels with splines=curved not supported in dot - use xlabels

but rather than using `xlabels`, the key is leaving `splines` alone.

Comment: I'm looking to replicate something like https://imgur.com/a/wOuaxvJ; I need the curved arrows. Not sure how I could have missed the fairly obvious warning.